# Authentication in .NET Core 3.1: Default options provide too little control and don't work as expected

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working with Identity and JWT auth in .NET Core 3.1.  I will be adding Open Id in the future.  The problem I am facing now is that I have too little control over the authentication pipeline. The pipeline makes some decisions for you, such as when to re-direct to the login.  For example, for Identity authentication, when you emit a 401 status it will attempt to re-direct to /login - even if you specified a different page in the cookie configuration.  Surprisingly, JWT auth has the same problem - even when the only policy supplied is the Bearer policy and the controller is tagged with the `ApiController` attribute.

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Schemes.Bearer)]`

I want full control over the pipeline and the response. What is the best way to achieve this by utilizing as much of the built in tools as possible? I do not wish to write my own JWT validating code, rather use the validation as I configured it.

This is how I configure JWT.  `OnAuthenticationFailed`.  The callback to set the headers manually never runs.

```
 //piranha
        services.AddPiranha(options =>
        {
            options.UseFileStorage(naming: Piranha.Local.FileStorageNaming.UniqueFolderNames);
            options.UseImageSharp();
            options.UseManager();
            options.UseTinyMCE();
            options.UseMemoryCache();
            options.UseEF<SQLiteDb>(db =>
                db.UseSqlite("Filename=./Data/emurse-piranha.db"));
            options.UseIdentityWithSeed<IdentitySQLiteDb>(db =>
                db.UseSqlite("Filename=./Data/emurse-piranha.db"),
                identityOptions =>
                {
                    // Password settings
                    identityOptions.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    identityOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                    identityOptions.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    identityOptions.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    identityOptions.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    identityOptions.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                    // Lockout settings
                    identityOptions.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
                    identityOptions.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                    // User settings
                    identityOptions.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                },
                cookieOptions =>
                {
                    cookieOptions.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    cookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/manager/login";
                    cookieOptions.AccessDeniedPath = "/manager/login";
                    cookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;

                    var defaultAction = cookieOptions.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
                    cookieOptions.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                    {

                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
                        {
                        response.StatusCode = 401;
                        response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte> 
                        (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("unauthorized.")));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return defaultAction(context);
                        }
                    };

                });


            //turn off for prod
            options.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation=true;
            
        });

        //JWT
        services.AddAuthentication(Schemes.Bearer)
            .AddApplicationJwt(Configuration);
 public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApplicationJwt(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration config)
        {


            builder.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                var issuer = config["Jwt:Issuer"];
                var key = config["Jwt:Key"];

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidAudience = issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
                };
                //Never executes
                options.Events= new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = ((context) =>         {
                       response.StatusCode = 401;
                       response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte> 
                       (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("unauthorized.")));
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }),
                     
                };
                 
            });

            return;
}
```

The app is then configured using mostly default options:

```
app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UsePiranha(options =>
        {
            options.UseTinyMCE();

            //default Auth middleware
            options.UseIdentity();

            app.UseCors(x => x
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) //TODO: remove for production
               .AllowCredentials());
            //use Piranha manager                
            options.UseManager();
        });
```

Comment: What is `Schemes.Bearer`? The default jwt scheme is `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

Comment: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme is just a string, Schemes.Bearer is set equal to JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme ("Bearer").

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the posted code. I use pretty much the same settings without issues. Could you show a bit more of your authentication/authorization setup?

Comment: @Xerillio I added some code showing the Piranha setup which is where the Auth gets configured. Doing a deep dive into the .NET Core & Identity source so hopefully I will have some more insight soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Xerillio, I've figured out the root cause of my problem.  After digging into the source code, I had a better understanding of what the extension methods are doing under the hood.

`UseAuthentication` adds the Authentication middleware.  But `UseIdentity` also does this, and `UseIdentity` is obsolete. Infact, ALL `UseIdenitity` does is call `UseAuthentication`.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();           
        app.UsePiranha();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UsePiranhaIdentity();

        //TODO: remove for production
        app.UseCors(x => x
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
           .AllowCredentials()); 

        app.UsePiranhaManager();
        app.UsePiranhaTinyMCE();
```

Comment: I don't know Piranha, but you should note that [UseIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.builderextensions.useidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is obsolete so you should try to avoid using it.